# PaymentSDK' for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, payment-gateway, paytm

I am integrate paytm gateway in ios app.As per document and link (https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/ios-sdk ).I import **SystemConfiguration.framework** in Link Binary With Libraries and **PaytmSDK.framework**  add in Embedded Binarie but when clean and build this product I got below error

> Ld /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-ffdfdfdfdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytmdemo.app/paytmdemo normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/administrator/Desktop/IOS Workplace/paytmdemo"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.2
>       export PATH="/Users/administrator/Desktop/ios app store/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/administrator/Desktop/ios app store/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Users/administrator/Desktop/ios\ app\ store/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Users/administrator/Desktop/ios\ app\ store/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk -L/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-bezjsagpjoyyohdzujzwppxblfbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-bezjsagpjoyyohdzujzwppxblfbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/administrator/Desktop/IOS\ Workplace/paytmdemo -filelist /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-bezjsagpjoyyohdzujzwppxblfbb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/paytmdemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytmdemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/paytmdemo.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=11.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-bezjsagpjoyyohdzujzwppxblfbb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/paytmdemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytmdemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/paytmdemo.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Users/administrator/Desktop/ios\ app\ store/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-bezjsagpjoyyohdzujzwppxblfbb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/paytmdemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytmdemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/paytmdemo.swiftmodule -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-bezjsagpjoyyohdzujzwppxblfbb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/paytmdemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytmdemo.build/paytmdemo.app.xcent -framework PaymentSDK -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-bezjsagpjoyyohdzujzwppxblfbb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/paytmdemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytmdemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/paytmdemo.dat -o /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/paytmdemo-bezjsagpjoyyohdzujzwppxblfbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/paytmdemo.app/paytmdemo
>
> ld: /Users/administrator/Desktop/IOS Workplace/paytmdemo/PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK compiled with newer version of Swift language (unknown ABI version 0x06) than previous files (4.0) file '/Users/administrator/Desktop/IOS Workplace/paytmdemo/PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK' for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I do not what happen.I integrate paytm gateway in my app so please check and help me

Comment: Here is your error ld: /Users/administrator/Desktop/IOS Workplace/paytmdemo/PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK compiled with newer version of Swift language (unknown ABI version 0x06) than previous files (4.0)

Comment: The Framework is compiled with newer version of Swift. You need to update your projects with Latest version of Swift

Comment: I convert to swift 3.2 to 4 but in my project i got 10 to 12 error.how to handle this error.

Comment: What sort of error you are getting? is Xcode giving suggestions to solve them?

Comment: var attributes = [String:AnyObject]()
    attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.black
    attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12.0)
    
    Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'NSAttributedStringKey'

Comment: var attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey:AnyObject]()
        attributes[.foregroundColor] = UIColor.black
        attributes[.font] = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12.0)